# Updating profile without updating password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parameters

I want to be able to update my user information without having to have the user set a password each time they edit any other attribute.

My current validations are:

```
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8 }
  validates :password_confirm, presence: true
```

how can I make this conditional? It would be clever to only require these validations if the password and password_confirm attribues were in the params. I could use some idea about how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you only want to validate the `password_confirm` if `password` has changed, correct? It shouldn't matter if you confirm that the password is present when a user edits another attribute, since the password will be present in the record (unlike `password_confirm`, which I assume is an `attr_accessor`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 8 }
validates :password_confirm, presence: true, :if => Proc.new { |a| a.password_changed? || a.new_record? }
```

See the docs on [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) for more on the `_changed?` methods. There should be no problem running the presence validation on `password` every time you change an attribute since this will persist in the DB, so it will always pass (whereas `password_confirm` will not persist and thus requires a conditional).