# validator :on is not working (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

In my User model i have the following validations:

```
  validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { minimum: 8 }, :on => :update_settings
```

if i don't use the `:on` validator it works work across the board. However with the :on I don't get any validation when executing the specified actions.

The form is going to: `action="/users/1/update_settings"`

The route is set up: `user_update_settings PUT    /users/:user_id/update_settings(.:format) users#update_settings`

I have checked the guide[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on). The same validation works on standard actions like :create but not on my own actions.

Can you see what else am I missing to make this validation valid? Thanks!

Comment: I thought `:on` was for things like :create, :update, etc, not arbitrary methods, but I could be remembering incorrectly. :save isn't an action, which makes me think it's more to do with the model lifecycle than action methods.

Comment: I think that :save is rails for update and create.

Comment: Correct; my point was that it is listed in the docs, and it isn't a default controller action, hence it's related to model lifecycle as opposed to action methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixed up about what the `:on` option is for. It is not for specifying actions on the *controller*, it is for specifying actions on the *record*. It would go totally against the MVC principle to tie controller actions to model validations in the way you're trying to do here.

Check the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on):

> The :on option lets you specify when the validation should happen. The default behavior for all the built-in validation helpers is to be run on save (both when you’re creating a new record and when you’re updating it). If you want to change it, you can use :on => :create to run the validation only when a new record is created or :on => :update to run the validation only when a record is updated.

So the `on` option takes one of only three possible values: `:save` (the default), `:update` or `:create`.

Given the name of your action (`update_settings`), I'm going to assume that in that action you are calling `update_attributes` (or `update_attribute`) on the model, in which case you should just use `:on => :update` in your validator. Note that this means that it will also apply the validation in any other controller actions that update the record, since the condition is not specific to any particular controller action.

Comment: well your first assumption is correct I am updating (using update_attributes) but I'm not updating the entire model. Just the settings (like password and image). So i don't want all the validations to occur if I'm only changing the password and vice versa.

Comment: I guess this question is now merging with my other question: How do i change the profile without updating the password and vice versa? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437778/updating-profile-without-updating-password/13437817#13437817 Maybe you can help me there too?

Comment: Posted an answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437778/updating-profile-without-updating-password/13445921#13445921